# how can i order the sql "SHOW DATABASES" statement in alphabetic order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I order the SQL: `SHOW DATABASES` statement in alphabetic order. It returns all databases in `MySQL` but it is not in order. I tried using `asort()` in my database array but it doesn't work.

```
$sql = "show databases";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee of order from `SHOW DATABASES`. If order is important, one should use a select against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` with an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
ORDER BY  `SCHEMATA`.`SCHEMA_NAME` ASC
```

Comment: awesome this works perfect. thanks alot. sorry i missed your comment

Answer (score -1):

What about ordering the results ?
Have a look : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: i tried sort() and asort() both dont work......$sql="show databases"; asort($sql); and sort($sql);

Comment: i foreach my result like this asort($sql); foreach($sql as $database_name){ $db=$database_name['Database']} isnt this what you mean?

Comment: Edit your SQL request, not your PHP. Sort the results in the request with the ORDER BY clause. Chetan Ameta just gave you a good example

Comment: How this link is relevant to the question?

Comment: thanks alot. Chetan's example worked . your help was appreciated

Comment: @ernys You're welcome.@Your Common Sense I just assumed he was not aware about the "ORDER BY" clause, and I found this link useful enough to introduce him to ordering with mysql.